# Show real server name in nginx logs and params passed to fastcgi?

Tags: nginx, logging, regex

I have configured my nginx vhosts with a regex in server_name. nginx shows the raw regex in logs and in params passed to php-fpm (I know there's `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with a real value, that's not an issue). My question is how can I get nginx to put the real hostname to logs, instead of the regex.

The server_name directive looks like this:

`server_name ~^(:?(?<second>.+)\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$;`

Answer (score 12):

Use `$http_host` in your `log_format` to get the actual host that the client sent.

You can also use that variable in `access_log` directives to split your logs by hostname.

Comment: Why not `$host`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Because its semantics don't match what this person wants. [See the docs.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host)

Comment: I understand this can be done for access logs. How should I modify the error logs? From what I've learned, it's not possible set custom format for them. (I'm trying to get split done by hostname, however it's giving me weird results right now – modified it and waiting for new entries.)

Comment: You can't modify the format of error logs, but you can certainly split them by host.

Comment: Okay, I have modified the directives like this:

`access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.$http_host.log;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.$http_host.log;`

but nginx creates file with name `error.$http_host.log` (without replacing for the acutal one) on restart. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Also pardon wrong formatting and editing, I'm yet not used to this comment system.

Comment: Good question. I'm quite sure I have this working somewhere, but I can't find the configuration right now.

Comment: The Nginx `error_log` directive does not allow you to use variables in the file name param like `acesss_log` does. This seems to be because `access_log` is handled by the log module, but `error_log` is in core and has a different implementation.